# Is there a way to dynamically generate Prolog rules from Java (based on user input)?

Tags: java, prolog, artificial-intelligence, jpl

Key word **dynamically.**

I've been trying out JPL for SWI-Prolog but as far as I can tell, all that can do is take a pre-written Prolog file and dynamically construct some queries to be run on that knowledge base. It has no way of actually adding to the knowledge base.

What I envisage is a user running the Java program being able to add rules to the Prolog knowledge base through some kind of command line interface (i.e. setting the properties of certain objects that the user creates in an interactive fiction story).

Can JPL do this? Can any Prolog interface? Or do I have to go back to finding a Java knowledge representation library that isn't either hugely overengineered (Cyc) or a buggy mess (Tweety)? If so, do you have any to recommend?

Comment: You can use `assertz/1` to assert a rule: `assertz(Head :- Body)`.

Comment: Is that a class method somewhere? I'm not seeing it in the API documentation.

Comment: @mat That should be `assertz((Head :- Body))` otherwise you'll get a syntax error in several systems.

Comment: An also ugly solution is to write your rules in a temp file and then use the `consult` predicate.